# Describe all of the homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_{24}$ to $\Bbb Z_{18}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

I am trying to figure out all of the homomorphisms between these groups.

First by homomorphisms properties, the identity of $\Bbb Z_{24}$ is mapped to $\Bbb Z_{18}$ (i.e $\phi(0) = 0$).

After that, I got a bit confuse since the different combinations of mapping between the groups do not seems clear to me. I tried to list all of the subgroups of both groups but I do not know how these informations are helpful to me.

Thank you,

Comment: Is there a generator of $\Bbb{Z}/24\Bbb{Z}$?  A generator has order the same as the group.  Suppose $g$ is such a generator.  Once you specify $\varphi(g)$, do the properties of homomorphisms force the image under $\varphi$ of every other element of $\Bbb{Z}/24\Bbb{Z}$?  There are at most $18$ place you can send $g$ in $\Bbb{Z}/18\Bbb{Z}$.  What happens with each of them?

Comment: yes so in this case, the homorphisms between the groups would be $ \phi(n)=xn$ where $x =0,4,8,12,16,20$ ?